# How to externalize Landoop Kafka connector common properties

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Landoop Kafka docker image. I am using its UI to create jdbc source and jdbc sink connector or I can also use Kafka Rest Api to create connectors. I have number of jdbc source connectors using same connection url, username, password. Whenever the source database credentials are changed, currently I have to change in all connectors individually. Is there a way I can externalize only these properties and let each connector have its specific properties like topic, query, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Added in Kafka 2.0, you can externalize secrets, at least. Ref [**KIP-297**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations).

I have yet to try it myself, and it *might* only be available for [`ConfigDef.Type.PASSWORD`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef.Type.html#PASSWORD) configurations, not just general ones...

Extract from the KIP

> The patterns for variable substitutions are of the form `${provider:[path:]key}`, where only one level of indirection is followed during substitutions.
>
> The path in the variable is optional.
>
> This means if you have the following:
>
> ```
> foo=${file:bar}
> bar=${file:baz}
> ```
>
> and your file contains
>
> ```
> bar=hello
> baz=world
> ```
>
> then the result will be
>
> ```
> foo=hello
> bar=world
> ```

So, in Docker, you could volume mount a config file, then reference it inside the connector config payload

Comment: So, lets say I create source-database-config.txt, sink-database-config.txt having common properties for source and sink connectors respectively, I could use in the connector config as {
    "name": "test-jdbcSourceConnector",
    "config": {
    "connector.class": ${source-database-config:class},
"connection.password"=${source-database-config:password}
"connection.user"=${source-database-config:username}, "connection.url": ${source-database-config:url}}

Comment: Well, `file:` is the default "provider" and so must be literally on every field. Therefore, it would rather look something like `${file:/source-database-config.txt:connector_class}`, where that is the provider, the path to the file, then the key property mentioned in the file